# Laravel jwt authentication howto (is my solution good?)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I have a number of laravel (5.4) apps.

The main app handles the registration, login, etc. Another apps need to use the main app's users table and authentication, so if somebody logs in the main app, the other apps should see him/her as a logged in user.

Working on this for a while, came up with JWT athentication (as another node.js app already uses this method to authenticate with the main laravel app). In node.js it is done with ajax, for example node app calls `https://www.mainapp.com/token`, and gets back a jwt token if present, then node decrypts this, and everything goes on.

As all laravel apps using the tymon/jwt-auth package, I can do just the same in the other laravel apps too, but seems to me a bit clumsy, is there any better way to share an authentication between apps?  Or a server-side solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your JWT is using your unique `JWT_SECRET`. So as soon as all your env files are running with the same env value for the `JWT_SECRET` you just have to use a middleware to check THE token and authenticate the user.

Also your JWT has quite a few parameters which you can investigate but some of the most important is the `exp` which is the expiration time and the `sub` which is the user id coming from your users table. So you got pretty much all the info you need.

Comment: right it grabs the token, decrypts it, and uses laravels built-in auth with the decrypted token data. is creating a new middleware better solution?

Comment: You just want your endpoints to be inside the scope of the authentication middleware.  You can use the jwt middleware itself to authenticate the endpoints and grant permission to access the controller